# REST Assured request is not read properly by JSON api

Tags: java, json, postman, rest-assured, json-api

I'm sending some string eg:

```
private final String test = "{\"data\":{\"type\":\"test\",\"attributes\":{\"color\":\"yellow\",\"name\":\"TestN\"}}}";
```

via Rest Assured

```
given()
            .header("Origin", "http://localhost:5000")
            .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
            .header("Accept-Language", "pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7")
            .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json")
            .header("Accept", "application/vnd.api+json")
            .header("Cookie", "xxxxxx")
            .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
            .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
            .header("Host", "localhost:4400")
            .body(test).with()
            .log().everything()
            .when()
            .post(base + "test-endpoint")
            .then().statusCode(201);
```

unfortunately API responds with 500. I'm sending identical request via Postman and it works perfectly. Only difference is "assings" section. After Postman request it looks like:

```
assigns: %{
 doc: %Jabbax.Document{
   data: %Jabbax.Document.Resource{
     attributes: %{"appointment_color" => "yellow", "name" => "TestN"},
     id: nil,
     links: %{},
     meta: %{},
     relationships: %{},
     type: "test"
   },
   errors: [],
   included: [],
   jsonapi: %{version: "1.0"},
   links: %{},
   meta: %{}
 }
},
```

when after Rest Assured request it's empty:

```
assigns: %{},
```

all of the headers are added and I've tried sending it as a string parsed from .json file. Everything gives same results. Somebody know what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The clue was that REST Assured added a charset information - similar issue was described here.